# Full-duplex communication over the same HTTP/2 request-response stream

Tags: http, request, streaming, response, full-duplex

I am trying to use a single HTTP/2 request-response stream as a full duplex communication channel between client (Chrome 114) and server (ASP.NET Core 7). I am using
ReadableStream/WritableStream in the client and PipeReader/PipeWriter in the server in order to simultaneously send (long request) and receive (long response). What I have found is that it works but the response is not read until the full request is written.

Why are the reads in my client code not printing simultaneously with the writes in my below code?

I could not set the fetch's duplex property to "full" because the browser does not recognize it. Is HTTP/2 not full-duplex in the browsers? Does the same apply for HTTP/3?

This is the client side code (see comments):

```js
let writeTotal = 0;
let readTotal = 0;

const reqStream = new ReadableStream({
    pull: (controller) => {
        controller.enqueue("Yousuf is lovely!\n");
        writeTotal += 18;

        // Why are writes printed all first then comes reads?
        console.log("Write: " + writeTotal);
        
        if (writeTotal === 18 * 100000) {
            controller.close();
        }
    },
});

const resStream = new WritableStream({
    write: (chunk) => {
        readTotal += chunk.length;
        
        // Why are reads not printed simultaneously with writes?
        console.log("Read: " + readTotal);
    }
})

const result = await fetch("https://localhost:8080/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: reqStream.pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream()),
    duplex: 'half' // Cannot set this to full!
});

await result.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).pipeTo(resStream);

console.log("Total Written: " + writeTotal);
console.log("Total Read: " + readTotal);
```

This is the server side code (see comment):

```cs
using System.Buffers;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Map("/", async (context) =>
{
    PipeReader reader = context.Request.BodyReader;
    PipeWriter writer = context.Response.BodyWriter;
    long total = 0;
    
    // This prints HTTP/2
    Console.WriteLine("New Request: " + context.Request.Protocol);
    
    while (true)
    {
        ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync();
        ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;
        SequencePosition position = buffer.GetPosition(0);
        string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Slice(position));
        
        Console.WriteLine("New Chunk: " + body.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(body.Substring(0, Math.Min(10, body.Length)));
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        await writer.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));

        reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.GetPosition(buffer.Length));

        total += body.Length;

        if (result.IsCompleted || result.IsCanceled || total == 18 * 100000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed? " + result.IsCompleted);
            Console.WriteLine("Canceled? " + result.IsCanceled);
            
            await reader.CompleteAsync();
            await writer.CompleteAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + total);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            
            break;
        }
    }
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/1254